# Why save method is working for one repository and not for the other?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have a method in my `Service` class

```
@Override
    public void addFilterDetails(FilterDetails filterDetails) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FilterDetails fd = new FilterDetails(filterDetails.getGender(),filterDetails.getAge(),filterDetails.getCity(),filterDetails.getState());
        filterDetailsRepository.save(fd);
    }
```

This is my repository

```
 package com.thoughtclan.segmentation_of_customers.repository;

    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import com.thoughtclan.segmentation_of_customers.model.Customer;
    import com.thoughtclan.segmentation_of_customers.model.FilterDetails;
    @Repository

    public interface FilterDetailsRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>{

    }

    @Override
        public void addCustomer(Customer custObj) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Customer customer = new Customer( custObj.getFirstName(), custObj.getLastName(),custObj.getEmail(),custObj.getGender(),custObj.getPhoneno(),custObj.getCity(),custObj.getState(),custObj.getAge());
            customerRepository.save(customer);
        }
```

`addCustomer()` is working with the exact same syntax, why is `filterdetails.save` giving the following error?

> CrudRepository is not applicable for the arguments (FilterDetails)

Comment: What error are you getting..??

Comment: The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<Customer,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (FilterDetails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you've created a Repository for `Customer` class.

```
public interface FilterDetailsRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>
```

In the above case it cannot let you `save` any type of Entity except `Customer`.

If you want to save the `FilterDetails` you have to create another Repository for `FilterDetails` like below :

```
public interface FilterDetailsRepository extends CrudRepository<FilterDetails, Long>
```

Then by reference of  `FilterDetailsRepository` you can save the `FilterDetails`

Comment: yeah u r rught...i cant believe i made such a stupid mistake

Comment: I just made the same mistake, 5 years later, and I realized my mistake with that question (: